# Add more generic types to a child extending a parent with generics

Tags: java, generics

I wanna make a hight abstract level. I got

```
public abstract class CrudRepositoryDtoConverter<R extends CrudRepository<E, Integer>, E, D> implements CrudDTO<D>
```

I would like to use it as parent for another abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractController
```

I tried multiples combinations, without success, e.g

```
public abstract class AbstractController<K extends CrudRepositoryDtoConverter<R extends CrudRepository<E, Integer>, E, D>> {
    @Autowired
    private K repository;

}
```

This one can't compile, I don't find the syntax for the generic types, am I wrong? Is my idea even possible?

Comment: You need to define E, R and D

Comment: u mean <K extends [...], E, D, R>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very complicated definition, but if you really need it, you can write it as follows :

```
abstract class AbstractController<R extends CrudRepository<E, Integer>, E, D, K extends CrudRepositoryDtoConverter<R, E, D>> {

}
```

As you see, `R`, `E` and `D` must be declared as generic type parameters of the class `AbstractController` in order for you to refer to them in `K extends CrudRepositoryDtoConverter<R, E, D>`.

Comment: how would I simplify `public class ActivityController extends AbstractController<ActivityRepository, Activity, ActivityDTO, ActivityRepositoryImpl>`

Comment: I need this to add basic CRUD methods for each controller, but 4 generic types.. lmao

Comment: @Romain I don't know. It's hard to answer based on the small snippet you posted.

Comment: @Romain I'm not sure. Perhaps you should post a new one. It's not a good idea to make big changes in a question after you already got an answer to the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152035/discussion-between-romain-and-eran).

Comment: @Romain I'm sorry, but I don't have time to chat at the moment.